# CSS background: want a diff. background for my other pages

Tags: css, background

I'm using CSS `background: url(stuffhere.jpeg)` for my background, but when you click on other videos, "projects" *not pages*, the background won't change.

I've tried `<body id="home">` and `<body id="projects">`, and tried making two backgrounds for #home and #projects but the projects won't work..

Then I used `<div id="projects">`, but the problem is that since it's not a page, div won't change the entire background.

Please check this out and let me know... [www.montagemd.com](http://www.montagemd.com), and then click on one of the videos. I want the grey background to fill the whole thing... or to over-ride what I have in #home

Comment: are you using javascript to change the CSS?

Comment: Please paste some relevant code. Preferrably in a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: i'm building the site on cargo collective... here is full html/background. http://jsfiddle.net/xhGE2/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can make the gray background fill the entire viewport by doing the following:

1. Giv the div a width of 100% and min-height of 100% (min-height will let it grow if its content is taller than the window).
2. Make sure the div's parent is the `<body>` with a 100% height defined on it as well.  Percentage heights only work if the element's parent has a height defined as well.

It'll look something like this in the code:

```
<body>
    <div id="gray-box"></div>
</body>
```

And then the CSS would be:

```
html, body {
    /* Defines a height on #gray-box's parents (required for % height to work) */
    height: 100%;

    /* Eliminate any extra spacing around #gray-box */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#gray-box {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%; /* Let #gray-box grow with its content */
    background: #ddd;
}
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xhGE2/) of it in action.

Comment: tried this but it won't work.. works on jsfiddle, but I'm building this site with cargo. for some reason the div is within a container which doesn't let it grow past a certain point

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xhGE2/1/ here is all the code i'm using. for home page i just have <body id="bg">. thanks for looking